# Least run time with threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have some functions that check for prime numbers in a given range and output the results to a text file. The function also requires the user to input how many threads the function will use.

```
#include "threads.h"
#include <thread>
#include <ctime>

bool isPrime(int n)
{
    if (n == 2)
        return true;

    int i = 2;
    while (i < n)
        if (n % i++ == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}

void writePrimesToFile(int begin, int end, ofstream& file)
{
    for (int i = (begin % 2 == 0 ? begin + 1 : begin); i <= end; i += 2)
        if (isPrime(i))
            file << i << endl;
}
void callWritePrimesMultipleThreads(int begin, int end, string filePath, int N)
{
    ofstream file(filePath);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        clock_t time = clock();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            int _begin = ((end - begin) / N) * i,
                _end = ((end - begin) / N) * (i + 1);
            thread t(writePrimesToFile, ref(_begin), ref(_end), ref(file));
            t.join();
        }

        cout << "Time elpased: " << (double(clock() - time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << endl;
        file.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "Can't open file!" << endl;
}
```

Here's the main:

```
#include "threads.h"

int main()
{
    callWritePrimesMultipleThreads(0, 1000, "primes.txt", 10);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to know, for which value of `N`, the amount of threads, the program will run the best.

Comment: More than likely it will be equal to the number of cores you have but you should profile it to find out.

Comment: It depends on many things, like the hardware you have, the operating system, how busy the operating system is, and probably other minor issues.

Comment: You already have the code. Why are you asking us instead of running and finding it out yorself?

Comment: The time will be exactly the same (or close), as you are waiting for each thread to finish *IN* the loop...

Comment: @VladFeinstein Good point.  I didn't see that.

Comment: Does this code ever claim that 2 is a prime?  It appears to only consider odd numbers.  Does it claim that 1 is a prime (it appears to).  It will run *very* much faster if `isPrime` calculates `int(sqrt(n))` and stops when `i` exceeds that.  It will run a bit faster still if it special cases i=2,3, then only considers `i=j*6 +/- 1`.  I bet my optimization of `isPrime` will beat your thread optimizations (even if you run on a octo-core processor).

Comment: You may get conflicts when threads try to write to the file at the same time.  Also, your output may not be sequential because different threads are writing at different times, think *interweaving output*.

Comment: On your system, there is a X amount of work that each thread needs to perform in order to account for thread creation and management overhead.  There is also Y amount of threads for which any more threads than Y will cause the OS to spend more time in thread management than the threads are executing.  You will need to run (profile) your program many times in order to weed out all these overhead times (such as other programs executing at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

An optimal solution to this problem would be to start N threads, each running the same function, that increments a shared counter (using InterlockedIncrement, for thread-safety), and calculates whether or not it is prime.

If you do this, and set N to the number of cores in your machine, you will get the optimal 100% CPU consumption, with zero context switches.

Regarding the output, notice that you can't safe write to one output file without locking (which you want to avoid). Instead, I would collect the prime numbers in an array or vectors (one vector for each thread), and eventually merge them into one vector, sort them and then write to file.